# Percentage of Restaurant Tables Appropriate for Wheelchairs

Tags: florida, disabilities

A local restaurant remodeled and now they have mostly high tables with stools and booths. They only have a few tables appropriate for someone in a wheelchair. If a restaurant has plenty of tables available, but none are suitable for a person in a wheelchair, are they ADA compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ADA Standards](https://www.ada.gov/regs2010/2010ADAStandards/2010ADAstandards.htm) , in section 226.1 requires that:

> Where dining surfaces are provided for the consumption of food or drink, at least 5 percent of the seating spaces and standing spaces at the dining surfaces shall comply with 902.

Where section 902 gives specifics on the requirements for accessible dining surfaces.

It therefore seems that, in order to determine compliance, you would need to know how many dining spaces are available in total, and how many are wheelchair accessible. If less than 5% are accessible then the restaurant is not compliant, otherwise they appear to be OK.

Comment: Thanks. The percentages are approximately 20% normal tables, 20% booths, 60% high tables. So, it appears that they are compliant. 5% is much lower than I expected, maybe the intent was that a restaurant would attempt to reserve them for those that really need them (?).

Comment: They don’t have to reserve them necessarily; when the restaurant fills they can tell a customer “you can use this table but if a wheelchair user arrives you’ll have to leave”. Don’t know what happens if all tables are full, but in that case I suppose everyone has to wait.